# Store list of objects in a table of serialized strings using EF core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an abstract type in a one-to-many relationship, and I want to store the objects as serialized data using EF core.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}

public class Blog
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Post
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class ConcretePost : Post
{
    public string SomeData { get; set; }
}
```

So far I have only been able to achieve this by serializing the entire set (Posts) but I want to have them serialized individually in a Posts table.

Can that be done using EF core?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.